# How to connect our own app to shopify database

Tags: android-studio

I want to connect my android app to shopify database for listing items from Shopify, to my app how to make this possible with source code.

Answer (score -1):

Use Shopify's Android Buy SDK: https://github.com/Shopify/mobile-buy-sdk-android/